# Is there an explicit formula for $\sum x^n/(n!)^2$?  

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!n!}x^{n}$, is there an explicit formula for $f(x)$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is, for $x \ge 0$, a special case of the modified Bessel function of the first kind. Have a look here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(n!)^{2}} = \mathrm{I}_0 \left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)
$$

Comment: formula added...

Comment: Here is a probabilistic interpretation of this equation: Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be iid Poisson random variables with rate $\sqrt{x}$. Then, $\mathbb P(X_1 = X_2) = e^{-2 \sqrt{x}} I_0(2 x)$.